# Angular2 method binding error: "value has changed after it was checked"

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, typescript, angular

I am trying to make a circle board in Angular2. For the example I want to make 10 circles but in reality this number can change. I want to calculate the radius of each circle, so it would be dynamic and not static. See the picture for example[image]

This is my code

```
@Component({
    selector:"circle"
    template: `
  <svg>
    <circle *ngFor='#item of forLength #i=index #l=last #e=even'
            cx="50%" cy="50%" [style.r]="calculateRadius()" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="white"></circle>
  <svg/>  
    `
})

export class CircleComponent{
    public maxRadius:number=25;
    public totalRounds:number=10;
    public x:number=30;

    public calculateRadius():number{
        var distanceBetweenCircles=this.maxRadius/(this.totalRounds-1);
        this.x-= distanceBetweenCircles;
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
calculateRadius() in CircleComponent@7:30' has changed after it was checked. 
    Previous value: '-7.500000000000007'. 
    Current value: '-36.66666666666668' in [calculateRadius() in CircleComponent@7:30]
```

Is there maybe a better way of writing this for loop with `*ngFor` instead of writing this in a separate method?

Comment: Where are you calling `calculateRadius()` in your template?  Where do you set the SVG `r` attribute in your template?

Comment: @MarkRajcok Sorry I have written a mistake in the code, I have now updated the code. I use calculateRadius() in the <circle> tag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In development mode (the default), change detection is [run twice](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#tick-anchor) to ensure that model changes have stabilized.  This means that the `ngFor` loop is evaluated twice.  Hence property `x` will continue to be decremented the second time change detection runs.  Other activity in your app will also cause change detection to run, and `x` will continue to be decremented.  Therefore, you must  write all view functions, like `calculateRadius()`, assuming they will be executed many times.  E.g.:

```
public calculateRadius(i):number{
    return this.x - i*this.distanceBetweenCircles;
}
```

The Template Syntax dev guide mentions this when it describes [idempotent expressions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#idempotence).

This will also solve the `value has changed after it was checked` problem.

You also need to bind SVG attribute `r` using this syntax:  `[attr.r]="..."`, not `[style.r]="..."`.

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZC7QibDz1xwKzmzJqLPy?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! There could not be a better explanation. It works now!

Comment: Since Angular2 RC3, you can solve this situation by changing the change detection stratedy: import {ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core'; @Component({changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush})

Comment: @BecarioSenior, I would not recommend using OnPush as a solution to this issue.  OnPush should be used with components that only depend on their input properties and there are no input properties here.  Even if we were to add an input property, a component method shouldn't modify the value the input property in this manner (in this scenario, such an input property should be read only, in my opinion).  Also, expressions used in templates should be idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

> “value has changed after it was checked”

The return from any `value` must be deterministic. Means if I call `value` (might be `calculateRadius()`) with the *same* inputs it should give the *same* output.

So pass `index` into `calculateRadius` (or whatever `value` is giving that error)