# How to enable production mode?

Tags: angular

I was reading related questions and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710895/angular2-method-binding-error-value-has-changed-after-it-was-checked), but my question is how can I switch from development to production mode. There are some differences between the modes which are pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868810/what-is-diff-between-production-and-development-mode-in-angular2).

In the console I can see `....Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.` However, I'm not sure instance of which type should I call that method on.

Can somebody answer this question?

Comment: I found it crazy passing configuration using Webpack 2+ Angular2 and Typescript, created a simple solution: https://github.com/Sweetog/yet-another-angular2-boilerplate

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You enable it by importing and executing the function (before calling bootstrap):

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(....);
```

But this error is indicator that something is wrong with your bindings, so you shouldn't just dismiss it, but try to figure out why it's happening.

Comment: How to enableProdMode() if you are not using typescript? If I just call this method before ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(...) I get this error: enableProdMode is not defined

Comment: @DanielDudas I don't use es5, but try `ng.core.enableProdMode()`

Comment: I believe "angular2/core" is now "@angular/core".  See my answer below.

Comment: I am using Ionic2. In what file is this bootstrap called? When I generate a sample app `ionic start test sidemenu --v2 --ts` I see `app.ts` but where is this bootstrap function called?

Comment: Found it using Ionic2. Edited `app.ts` imported `import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core'` And put `enableProdMode();` before `@App`

Comment: I did the same but I'm getting an exception like "Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup". Could anyone help me in getting this resolved?

Comment: using `angular-cli` execute `ng build` with `--env=prod`

Comment: How to do this using node `require`?

Comment: Can you elaborate regarding the binding issue?

Comment: Is `ng build --prod` the same as doing `ng build --env=prod`?

Comment: How would i use this with an individual test that has different behavior depending on whether it's run with dev or prod?

Comment: @Sasxa I didn't realize this was indicating that there was something wrong with bindings. I thought everyone would see this message when running in dev mode. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 115):

The best way to enable the production mode for an Angular 2 application, is to use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and build the application with `ng build --prod`. This will build the application with production profile. Using angular-cli has the benefit of being able to use development mode using `ng serve` or `ng build` while developing without altering the code all the time.

Comment: I'm using Angular 6 and it's ng build --prod to build in prod mode. Just putting this here for any newcomers visiting this page.

Comment: I think that _build --prod_ has been implemented keeping isDevMode and enableProdMode in mind. This answer should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 66):

When I built a new project using angular-cli.  A file was included called environment.ts.  Inside this file is a variable like so.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

**Then in main.ts you have this.**

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**You could add this to a non angular-cli project, I would assume, because enableProdMode() is being imported from @angular/core.**

Comment: How does this work for non-prod build? I assume in that case environment.ts is ignored, so don't you get a tsc compile error when trying to import the module?

Comment: @llasarov the environment.ts is just behaving like a configuration file, in which you can turn on/off production mode. The main.ts just calls the enableProdMode if its true, so this can be done without any specific build process. You can also do selecting logging here, by checking if the logMode is debug then your custom logger service doing a detailed StackTrace else just logging a one liner

Answer (score 63):

This worked for me, using the latest release of Angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.1):

**main.ts**

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(....);
```

Here is the function reference from their docs: https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode

Comment: new link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/enableProdMode-function.html

Comment: @emp I'm surprised the official Angular documentation for `enableProdMode` doesn't tell you *where* you're supposed to call it.

Answer (score 15):

Go to `src/enviroments/enviroments.ts` and enable the production mode

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

for Angular 2

Answer (score 11):

To enable production mode in angular 6.X.X
Just go to environment file

Like this path

Your path: `project>\src\environments\environment.ts`

Change `production: false` from :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

To

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`ng build --prod` replaces environment.ts with environment.prod.ts

`ng build --prod`

Comment: This is deprecated now.

Answer (score 9):

Most of the time prod mode is not needed during development time. So our workaround is to only enable it when it is **NOT** localhost.

In your browsers' `main.ts` where you define your root AppModule:

```
const isLocal: boolean = /localhost/.test(document.location.host);
!isLocal && enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The `isLocal` can also be used for other purposes like `enableTracing` for the `RouterModule` for better debugging stack trace during dev phase.

Answer (score 9):

For **Angular v12** and onwards `ng build --prod` has been deprecated.

You should now build it using `ng build --configuration=production` where again as before

the `src/environments/environment.ts` file is replaced with the target-specific version of the file, `src/environments/environment.prod.ts`.

Answer (score 8):

In environment.ts file set production to true

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

Comment: Really EZ :P TY for...!

Answer (score 6):

When ng build command is used it overwrite environment.ts file

By default when ng build command is used it set dev environment

In order to use production environment, use following command
ng build --env=prod

This will enable production mode and automatically update environment.ts file

Comment: This was changed in Angular CLI 6 to `ng build --configuration=production` (as default using the CLI-generated angular.json file).

Answer (score 5):

you can use in your app.ts || main.ts  file

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();
bootstrap(....);
```

Answer (score 4):

For those doing the upgrade path without also switching to TypeScript use:

```
ng.core.enableProdMode()
```

For me (in javascript) this looks like:

```
var upgradeAdapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();
ng.core.enableProdMode()
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['fooApp']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any environment.ts or such file to be provided by your seed project. Just have a configuration.ts and add all such entries which require runtime decision (example:- logging configuration and urls). This will fit in any design structure and also help in future

**configuration.ts**

```
export class Configuration {

   isInProductionMode : bool = true;

   // other configuration
   serviceUrl : string = "http://myserver/myservice.svc";
   logFileName : string = "...";
}
```

// Now use in your startup code (main.ts or equivalent as per the seed project design

```
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
....
if (Configuration.isInProductionMode)
    enableProdMode();
```

Comment: how do you differentiate prod/dev with that `isInProductionMode` to be true/false? in the build time?

Comment: Usually as a GULP parameter or equivalent

Comment: The JSON has entry as following: -"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }

Answer (score 3):

As of **Angular 15** it is no longer required to call the `enableProdMode()` function. Production mode is rather automatically selected by building with the optimization parameter (see https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode#description)

Answer (score 2):

Just write:
ng s --prod

This will serve the project as if you are on prod mode

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 10 :

> Find the file path **./environments/environment.ts** under your **'app'** and set **'production'** to **'true'**.

Before change:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

After change:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

`ionic serve --prod`

or

`ng build --prod`

Angular is running in development mode. Call `enableProdMode()` to enable production mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run angular in production or development mode with single ng serve command

Read on...

---

Step 1:

```
$ ng generate environments
```

This command generates these files;

1. src\environments\environment.ts
2. src\environments\environment.prod.ts
3. src\environments\environment.development.ts

Step 2:
Edit angular.json (found in same level as package.json of your project)
Add following lines in projects>architect>build>configurations>production:

```
"fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

You may notice i skip the development part, because this is already added, when you run 'ng generate environments'.

Step 3:
In your component class

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

And, also add

```
navBgColor = environment.bgColor;
```

---

> **Run ng serve commands**
>
> - For Production 
>    ng serve -c production --open
> - For Development 
>    ng serve -c development --open

Logic explained: 
For 'Development'
environment.ts will be replaced by environment.development.ts
For 'Production'
environment.ts will be replaced by environment.prod.ts
Note that, to see the difference, the value 'bgColor' has to be different, between environment.prod.ts and environment.development.ts.

Example:

environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  bgColor: 'red',
  production: true
};
```

environment.development.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  bgColor: 'cyan',
  production: false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My Angular 2 project doesn't have the "main.ts" file mentioned other answers, but it does have a "**boot.ts**" file, which seems to be about the same thing.  (The difference is probably due to different versions of Angular.)

Adding these two lines after the last `import` directive in "boot.ts" worked for me:

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
enableProdMode();
```

Answer (score 0):

before deployment always build in prod mode.
this message comes when it the build is done in development mode.
in development mode anyone can view the entire angular source code using any browser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure this answers the question? OP appears to be asking _how_ do do this, not whether they should. Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

in your file:

> **src => environment => environment.ts**

and you change (production value from false to true) this:

> export const environment = {
> **production: false**
> };

to that:

> export const environment = {
> **production: true**
> };

Answer (score 0):

I think from angular v15 and above, you don't necessarily need to specify production or development mode because it automatically has a default fallback depending on whether you are running `ng build` or `ng serve`.

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/tasky",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "tasky:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "tasky:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

this is a sample code of the build and serve section in the **angular.json** file. clearly in the serve and build objects the is a last **defaultConfiguration** property which is either set to production or development. this tells us that to run your app in **dev** mode run `ng serve` and to run in **prod** mode run `ng build`. but regardless you can still **serve** in **prod** mode by setting the **--configuration** flag to **prod** mode and same goes to **build**.