# Issue in angularjs2 with restful web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing AngularJS2 with Restful web API , and getting some console errors while calling HTTP post. Errors are listed below,

[image]
Hope you help

Controller code snippet

```
namespace SoomWebApi.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:64336", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage UserLogin([FromBody] LoginRequestData objValidate)
        {
            UserModelManager _UserModelManagerr = new Models.UserModelManager();

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _UserModelManagerr.Login(objValidate), GetJSONFormatter());

        } 
    }
}
```

Webapiconfig code snippet

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer [Old Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721206/how-to-enable-production-mode-in-angular-2) that will help you solve first error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like a CORS problem .. try to put in your  Startup.cs file in WebAPI something like:

```
 using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            ConfigureAuth(app);

        }
```

If you want to limit to some specific host ..try something like:

```
  var corspolicy = new corspolicy
            {
                allowanymethod = true,
                allowanyheader = true,
                supportscredentials = true,
                origins = { "http://www.example.com", "http://localhost:38091", "http://localhost:39372" }

            };

            app.usecors(new corsoptions
            {
                policyprovider = new corspolicyprovider
                {
                    policyresolver = context => task.fromresult(corspolicy)
                }
            });
```

Comment: Allow all is good for a dev environment, but do appropriate config in production mode.

Comment: created a Startup.cs insideApp_Start folder ,and included your code.But couldn't find any extention like UseCors

Comment: you don't have to create it... webapi asp.net scaffolding do it for you (int inside app_start..but in root path) .. and you need to install Nuget packages ..try to type in nuget UI ...owin CORS

Comment: no you put it not in the correct file and in the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Your server should support CORS to allow access from different domains. Update your server configuration to allow only predefined set of domains to allow access.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "domains"
```

If you have this problem on debug only and do not plan use CORS after deploy - mostly local web server starts your Angular application on **localhost:some-port** and server deployed on localhost also - use IE for debugging - it works good even when your angular middleware and backend works on different ports.

Answer (score 0):

If the code in production will be on the same domain as REST API, you can install chrome extension to avoid CORS error:

[Chrome CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)