# Error in enabling production mode in angular 4

Tags: php, html, css, angular

I am a beginner for angular 4. I am trying to make a simple example but whenever I am going to enable production mode `enableProdMode();`. this function gives me an error. tell me where I should write this. Tell me where should I write this function and why?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  enableProdMode();
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It gives me

> C:/Users/Home/Desktop/angdemo/second/src/app/app.module.ts (18,3): ','
>   expected.

Comment: enableProdMode(); <-- ";" must be a comma

Comment: Hey Eliseo after giving comma(,) like this   
enableProdMode(), it gives me another error :
 
ERROR in C:/Users/Home/Desktop/angdemo/second/src/app/app.module.ts (17,19): '{' expected.

Comment: Please put more care into what you write, you have a mistake in the title (!) which means you never even read it once.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not necessary to import

```
 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
```

inside app.module.ts, you can have an environment.ts or main.ts to defined the mode and import it. Remove it from **`app.module.ts`**, it should be fine.

Comment: Sajeetharan I already have all this things in main.ts 
my main.ts:
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) { enableProdMode();}platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
 .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: but after compiling successfully I got this one as Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.thats why I am trying to eanable production mode in app.module.ts  as mentioned in 
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721206/how-to-enable-production-mode-in-angular-2 "

Comment: @Sonu yeah but not in app.module.ts its in main.ts

Comment: Thanks  
Sajeetharan,

export const environment = {
  production: true
}; in envirnment.ts worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Use the code like this : you should not call `enableProdMode()` inside `@NgModule`.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


  enableProdMode();

export class AppModule { }
```