# Run specific test in production mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My tests are running in dev mode (`isDevMode()` returns `true`). Now, for one specific test, I want to test the components behavior in production mode.

What is best practice for this? Can I just turn on `enableProdMode()` or should I write a whole spec or even a suite for this?

Comment: Do you use angular cli?

Comment: @smnbbrv Yes, I do

Comment: [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721206/how-to-enable-production-mode-in-angular-2)