# Angular is running in the development mode

Tags: angular, security, development-mode

I'm not super familiar with Angular, but I just started at a company and I inherited a website that displays `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.` in the console. My first question, and main concern, is does being in Development mode make our site vulnerable in any way? I need to decide how high of a priority this should be.

Comment: Yes it does. You should not host a production site using the dev server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721206/how-to-enable-production-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the main difference as you might know is dev environment or mode(in your case) is just for development and testing purpose. And prod or production mode is for communicating with actual clients. So, to prevent mixing your test data with actual client data, dev is created. You can simply decide on which server or database you want to test, there you can use dev mode and when you go to production, just enableProdMode.

[image]